# Object of class App\Models\Product could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel-livewire

If i want to make increase button > product quantity show an alert message, what should i do if my product details.blade.php:

```
<div class="quantity" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <span>Quantity:</span>
                        <div class="quantity-input">
                            <input type="text" name="product-quatity" value="1" data-max="120" pattern="[0-9]*" wire:model="qty" >
                            <a class="btn btn-reduce" href="#" wire:click.prevent="decreaseQuantity"></a>
                            <a class="btn btn-increase" href="#" wire:click.prevent="increaseQuantity"></a>
                            @if(Session::has('message'))
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
                            @endif 
                        </div>
</div>
```

and my product details controller:

```
public function increaseQuantity(Product $product_quantity)
{
    if($this->qty >= $product_quantity) {
        $this->qty++;
    }
    else {
        session()->flash('message', 'No stock available!');
    }
}
```

Comment: share Product model with us as well

Answer (score 0):

You are using route model binding:
`public function increaseQuantity(Product $product_quantity)`
So Laravel pass Product model instance, it Means in your code the $product_quantity is a Product model based on the number you are sending on URL.
As we do not know about your model and its fields, I can say that if the product_quantity is a field in the Product Model so you need to change your code to this:
`if($this->qty >= $product_quantity->product_quantity)`

And if you want to send product_quantity straight from URL you need to remove Product as a parameter type and add int:
`public function increaseQuantity(int $product_quantity)`

Comment: I just changed my code to be like your directive above, then an error appears:
Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [ <required> int $product_quantity ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\DetailsComponent.